# How do I fix 'too many close_wait connections are created' even though the connections have been closed?

Tags: sockets, netty

The problem recently began on a server, there were too many sockets in close_wait state on the server, After increasing the server configuration the problem goes away, but the previous configurations are enough for the server. What might be the problem. The server is running on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Sounds like the server is not closing its sockets correctly. `CLOSE_WAIT` means the server has received a `FIN` from a client but has not sent a `FIN` back to the client to transition the socket into the `LAST_ACK` and then `CLOSED` states.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So this means that the server and not the code to close the socket is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is solved now, There was a bug in other part of the software which was consuming more CPU, thus eating up all the resources and not giving the server the resources to close the connections.

Comment: Right !  The side has CLOSE_WAIT state means there is some software trouble on that side,  in most cases is wrong code, (for example thread pool not release the resource, we need add a idle resource monitor)